# UIImagePickerController appears but camera doesn't start on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app where I present a `UIImagePickerController` with source type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. Everything works fine unless I leave the app and come back (multitasking is enabled so the app comes back right where it left off) and I present the `UIImagePickerController` again. It appears on screen but the camera never shows, the animation where the camera is revealed never happens, here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot]

If I press cancel and present the `UIImagePickerController` again, the camera will show up fine. So the only time this problem occurs is the first time I present the `UIImagePickerController` after coming back to the app. Anyone know why this is happening? I'm coding for iOS 5

I'm presenting the `UIImagePickerController` with:

```
[self presentViewController:capturePhotoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and dismissing it with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am using the same `UIImagePickerController` object each time I present it

Comment: Change it to [self presentModalViewController:capturePhotoPicker animated: YES]; the camera is Modal.

Comment: CodaFi, you are suggesting an outdated method of presenting modal view controllers, sorry but that does not help. (According to Apple, the presentViewController:animated:completion: method is the preferred way of presenting any view controller, you simply adjust the presentation style to make it modal, etc.)

Comment: Apple does not allow stacking of navigation bars. Since the image picker has its own navigation bar, it cannot be placed in a navigation stack. E.G. Modal Or None.  And what do you mean by "Outdated"?  That couldn't be any farther from the truth.  Outdated means deprecated, and presentModalViewController doesn't seem to throw me the deprecation warning :P

Comment: CodaFi, I did not say deprecated, I think you need to read up on what's new in iOS 5 :) "The presentViewController:animated:completion: method is the preferred way to present a modal view as of iOS 5.0." -Apple. This is not an issue of presenting a view modally, both methods produce the same result. Fyi, there is no navigation bar when the UIImagePicker is set to camera.

Comment: See this answer has solved my simlar kind of problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759194/displaying-uiimagepickercontroller-within-another-uiview/2961480#2961480

Comment: @ArpitParekh it didn't help me any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and then realized I wasn't releasing the `UIImagePickerController` after presenting it. The camera now works fine first-time after leaving and returning to the app.

So this is my exact code:

```
UIImagePickerController *takePhotoController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
takePhotoController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
takePhotoController.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:takePhotoController animated:YES];
[takePhotoController release];
```

It's one of those problems you can spend ages on, and the solution is not that obvious (well, it wasn't to me), so I hope this helps some people!

Comment: releasing/retaining objects is for the dinosaur age. you should use ARC and let the system take care of it for you.

Comment: I am using ARC and I still have the save problem

Answer (score 0):

if you change the -(void)viewDidLoad to - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated it fixes the problem. I've spent the last 2 weeks trying to figure this out