# UIImagePIckerController appears but the camera does not start

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.5

Yes, It might be a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283063/uiimagepickercontroller-appears-but-camera-doesnt-start-on-ios-5). But since it didn't get an answer, I will be more specific on the case and code:

I have 3 involved `UIViewControllers`:

1. `WelcomeView` - the first one
2. `TakePhotoViewController` - the second one who is delegate of the OverlayviewController
3. `OverlayViewController` - custom view for the camera.

Scenario:

1. User enter `WelcomeView` and clicks on a button to be transfered with segue to `TakeView`.
2. `UIImageViewController` is being opened to take a photo.
3. The user clicks on cancel button - `didCancelCamera` method in `TakePhotoViewController`  is being invoked and he returns to `WelcomeView`
4. The user leaves the app.
5. The user re-opens the app and perform step 1 again.

THE IMAGE PICKER IS NOT BEING OPENED. I COULD TAKE A PHOTO AND IT'S OK - BUT THE USER CAN'T SEE WHAT HE IS TAKING.

```
OverlayViewController.h

@interface OverlayViewController : BaseViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<OverlayViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
@end

OverlayViewController.m:


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
    [self.imagePickerController takePicture];
}

- (IBAction)cancelImagePicker:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate didCancelCamera];
}

- (void) setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) sourceType
{
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
        if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] ==0)
        {
            CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame)-self.view.frame.size.height-10.0, CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame), self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);
            self.view.frame = newFrame;
            [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
        }
    }
}


- (void)finishAndUpdate
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    [self.delegate didFinishWithCamera];  // tell our delegate we are done with the camera
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self finishAndUpdate];
}

TakePhotoViewController.h

@interface TakePhotoViewController : BaseViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,OverlayViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) OverlayViewController *overlayViewController;
@end

TakePhotoViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    // Insert the overlay
    self.overlayViewController = (OverlayViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Overlay"];
    self.overlayViewController.delegate = self;   
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.overlayViewController = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
- (void)openImagePicker {
   if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
       [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
   }
   else{
       [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
   }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (appDelegate.shouldOpenPicker){
      [self openImagePicker];
    }
}
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
    {
       [self.overlayViewController setupImagePicker:sourceType];
       [self presentViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
-(void)didCancelCamera{
    [[self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^ {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromTakeToWelcome" sender:self];
    }];

}
```

Comment: are you testing on iphone or ipad?

Comment: iPhone and iPad have the same problem. I tried on both

Comment: Did you set the background color of OverlayViewController's view to clear?

Comment: @rdelmar yes. in viewDidLoad method. Sorry I forgot to add it above but I edited my question

Comment: did you tried debugging the app and see if any condition fails ?

Comment: I copied your code into a new project, and it worked properly for me. The one thing I had to do differently was to make my two controllers subclasses of UIViewController instead of BaseViewController since you didn't show the code for that. Perhaps, that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Did you also add a button cancel to go back to welcome screen? Are u using storyboard?

Comment: I found the bug. The method -(void)didCancelCamera from TakePhotoViewController is being called when the user clicks on - (IBAction)cancelImagePicker:(id)sender in OverlayViewController. However, somehow the code in didCancelCamera causes viewDidAppear method of TakePhotoViewController to be invoked again and reopen the image picker. Why would it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.

The method

`-(void)didCancelCamera` from `TakePhotoViewController` is being called when the user clicks on `- (IBAction)cancelImagePicker:(id)sender` in `OverlayViewController`.

However, somehow the code in `didCancelCamera` causes `viewDidAppear` method of `TakePhotoViewController` to be invoked again and reopen the image picker.

I have no idea why

```
[[self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^ {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromTakeToWelcome" sender:self];
    }];
```

causes the viewDidAppear method of that view (TakePhoto) being recalled again.

Hope that it will help someone