# iOS UIImagePickerController freezes when opened

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, freeze

I'm currently working on an iPad app to run in iOS 6

I've implemented a subclass of UIImagePickerController in my app that forces the camera to be in landscape orientation by overriding the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` and `- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` functions.

There seems to be a random chance that upon launching the image picker via `presentViewController` it will get caught on the camera "loading" screen. The one that looks like a closed camera shutter. The app will freeze on this screen unless you exit out of it or lock/unlock the screen, after which it will function correctly.

I also have a custom UI for the camera view. However I was noticing this issue before I added that in, so I think it's unrelated.

Here's what I have to open the picker:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    self.modalController = [[CameraLandscapeImagePicker alloc] init];
    self.modalController.delegate = self;
    self.modalController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.modalController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
    self.modalController.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self.viewController presentViewController:modalController animated:YES completion:nil];

    //add the overlaying view ui
    [self.modalController buildCustomOverlay];

    self.newMedia = YES;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

[EDIT] - Update:
I have managed to figure out how to intentionally replicate this issue. Bellow are steps:

- tap my apps "capture" button to load up the camera
- exit the camera interface
- press the home button on the ipad
- open the app again by tapping it's icon on home screen
- tap my apps "capture" button again
- camera freezes on shutter screen

I also noticed that it occurs even when connected to xcode.

I have modified my code so that the UIImagePickerController object is provided via a singleton. Previously I was creating a new UIImagePickerController object each time. This has not had any effect and I am still getting the same issue.
I've left the app running on the shutter screen for about 5 minutes now and it is still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figured out what the problem was.

In the custom UI view that I added as the `cameraOverlayView` of the `UIImagePicker` I had a custom NavigationBar view.
This view had it's delegate set to the UIImagePicker and the delegate property used `retain`.

In the end it was a single word change from "retain" to "assign" to fix it:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id  delegate;
```

If you're having a similar issue to this I recommend commenting out parts of your custom ui code to see what exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, and already had a weak property for the delegate (also tried using assign), yet the problem persisted.

I found my problem was assigning directly the `UIImagePickerController`'s `cameraOverlayView` like so:

```
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay;
```

changing it to the following worked

```
[self.picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.overlay];
```

I found the solution in an Apple sample app:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

***EDIT*** After further testing, I found this was actually not enough.

As suggested in this post:
[Displaying UIImagePickerController within another UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759194/displaying-uiimagepickercontroller-within-another-uiview/2961480#2961480)

I added the following to get the shutter animation to "open":

```
[self.picker viewWillAppear:YES];
[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:NO completion:nil];
[self.picker viewDidAppear:YES];
```