# Using UIImagePickerController in UIView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have button which when I click displays the camera (works perfectly)

```
- (IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"Button clicked!" );
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }

    else {  // IF the device doesn't have a camera, so use the photos album
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    }

    [self addSubview:imagePicker.view];
}
```

After which I can take an image, etc, - But when I click "use" : nothing happens here is my method : the Image picker does not dismiss itslelf : the application simply does nothing, I'm trying to take the image I just took and display it inside a CGRect on screen .

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    UIImageView *patientImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    patientImage.frame = CGRectMake(625, 25, 83, 103);

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.patientImage.image = chosenImage;
}
```

Even when I hit the cancel button without taking an image, the imagePicker (camera interface) does not dismiss itself

Any help, advice, or guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: patientImage.frame = CGRectMake(625, 25, 83, 103); here is x is out of device screen :( so you can not see image and also [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; at the end of method

Comment: thank You Nitin, but I'm using an ipad, so it is in my screen, and I've tried to relocate the dismissVieController, with no success

Comment: is patientImage added to any view? like [self addSubview:patientImage];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `getPhoto:` method in the `UIView` subclass?

If thats the case, then it would be better to:

1. Move the `getPhoto:` code out of the `UIView` subclass entirely, and put it in the view's parent view controller.
2. Make your `UIButton` a property of your UIView: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myButton;`
3. In your view controller, set the button's target & action as follows:

   ```
   [myView.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```
4. Finally, in your `getPhoto:` method, call `[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];`
5. Your `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` code should also go in the view controller, changing `self.patientImage.image = chosenImage;` to `myView.patientImage.image = chosenImage;`

Comment: When I place line 3 in the viewdidload method of the ViewController class I get an error saying "PicBtn not found on object of type myView" - but I've declared PicBtn as a UIButton and as a property in the header of my UIView Class "myView"

Comment: For those also interested int his question What @vinnyCoyne said was the right thing to do . . . . but instead of calling

    `myView.myButton` 

you must create an instance of the myView Class first and then call it using the name of the instance variable. 

This solved my problem  . .  Thank you

Answer (score 5):

[You shouldn't be doing the "`addSubview`" thing up there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759194/displaying-uiimagepickercontroller-within-another-uiview) but instead do:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The problem is presentViewController is a method of UIViewController, I need this application to be working inside UIView, any idea?

Comment: A view should not be responsible for presenting another controller. This goes against MVC, which is at the core of iOS. You should have a view controller do this, as suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding the picker as a subview, you should add the picker to a `UIPopoverController`.

You can then display it from within your `UIView` subclass by using the `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` popover method like this:

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Then, you can use the delegate methods to dismiss the popover using:

```
[self.popover dismissPopoverAnimatedYES];
```

The is required by the [official docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

> The table indicates that on iPad, if you specify a source type of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or
>   `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, you must present
>   the image picker using a popover controller, as described in
>   “Presenting and Dismissing the Popover” in UIPopoverController Class
>   Reference. If you attempt to present an image picker modally
>   (full-screen) for choosing among saved pictures and movies, the system
>   raises an exception.
>
> On iPad, if you specify a source type of
>   `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, you can present the image
>   picker modally (full-screen) or by using a popover. However, Apple
>   recommends that you present the camera interface only full-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know why the cancel button is not working.
But make this change it will select the image you are clicking.

If you want an cancel event add it by creating custom `UIBarButton`and add it.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImageView *patientImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
patientImage.frame = CGRectMake(625, 25, 83, 103);

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.patientImage.image = chosenImage;

[imagePicker.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];

    UIImageView *patientImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    patientImage.frame = CGRectMake(625, 25, 83, 103);

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.patientImage.image = chosenImage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `[self.addSubView:imagePicker.view];` and instead

`[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];`

You are dismissing the variable `picker` although `picker` is undefined. Instead put:

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];` 
and make sure its at the end of your method.